# Laplace equation with weird boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I want to solve the following problem $$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0,$$ for $0<x<\infty$ and $0<y<\infty$ with the conditions $u(x,0)=0$, $u_y(0,y)=-\frac{q_0}{k}$ for $0<y<L$ and $u_y(0,y)=0$ for $y\ge L$. I tried using separation of variables ending, assuming $\lambda=\mu^2$ for $\mu$ real, with $$X(x)=c_1\cos \mu x+c_2\sin \mu x,$$ $$Y(y)=c_3\exp\{\mu y\}+c_4\exp\{-\mu y\},$$ but I don't know how to use the boundary conditions at this point. Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Probably it can be useful to try conformal mapping method?

Comment: Is $q_0/k$ constant?

Comment: And are you sure your boundary condition is on $u_y(0, y)$, not $u_x(0,y)$?

Comment: It comes from a heat flow along the $x=0$ axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the boundary condition $u(x,0)=0$, it's more appropriate to work with the functions
\begin{align}
X(x)&=c_1e^{\mu x}+c_2e^{-\mu x}, \tag{1} \\
Y(y)&=c_3\sin(\mu y). \tag{2}
\end{align}
One should also require that $u$ vanishes at infinity, which implies $c_1=0$ in Eq. $(1)$. The solution to the PDE must have the form
$$
u(x,y)=\int_0^{\infty}A(\mu)e^{-\mu x}\sin(\mu y)\,d\mu. \tag{3}
$$
To determine $A(\mu)$ we use the remaining boundary condition:
$$
u_y(0,y)=\int_0^{\infty}\mu A(\mu)\cos(\mu y)\,d\mu
=\begin{cases}
-\frac{q_0}{k}&\text{if $0<y<L$,} \\
0&\text{if $y\geq L$.}
\end{cases} \tag{4}
$$
We recognize $\mu A(\mu)$ as the [Fourier cosine transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine_transforms) of the function on the RHS of $(4)$. The inverse transform is given by
$$
\mu A(\mu)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^L\left(-\frac{q_0}{k}\right)\cos(\mu y)\,dy
=-\frac{2q_0\sin(\mu L)}{\pi k\mu}. \tag{5}
$$
Plugging $(5)$ into $(3)$ we finally obtain$^{(*)}$
\begin{align}
u(x,y)&=-\frac{2q_0}{\pi k}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\mu^2}e^{-\mu x}\sin(\mu L)\sin(\mu y)\,d\mu \\
&=-\frac{2q_0}{\pi k}\left\{\frac{|y+L|}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{|y+L|}{x}\right)
-\frac{|y-L|}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{|y-L|}{x}\right)\right. \\
&\qquad\qquad\,\,+\left.\frac{x}{4}\ln\left(\frac{x^2+(y-L)^2}{x^2+(y+L)^2}\right)\right\}.\tag{6}
\end{align}

---

$^{(*)}$ I. S. Gradshteyn and I. M. Ryzhik, [Table of Integrals, Series, and Products (8th Edition)](http://drhuang.com/science/mathematics/book/Table%20of%20Integrals,Series%20and%20Products%20Eighth%20Edition.pdf), formula $3.947.2$.

Comment: Thanks!! Can you check out this question? Is similar but now the initial conditions are harder https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4846340/laplace-equation-with-mixed-conditions

Answer (score 2):

**A partial solution**

Separation of variables is the right way to begin. Take simple solutions of the form $X(x)Y(y)$ where $X(x) = c_1(k)e^{kx} + c_2(k)e^{-kx}$ and $Y(y) = d_1(k)\cos ky + d_2(k)\sin ky$, where we can assume $k\geq 0$. For bounded solutions as $x\to\infty$ we need $c_1(k) = 0$, and since $u(x, 0) = 0$, $d_1(k) = 0$. This suggests the form
\begin{equation*}
u(x, y) = \int_0^\infty\, A(k)e^{-kx}\sin ky\, dk.
\end{equation*}
To satisfy the boundary condition at $x = 0$, at least as it's currently stated, involves
\begin{equation*}
u_y(0, y) = \int_0^\infty\, kA(k)\cos ky\, dk
\end{equation*}
and you'll need to look up in a table of Fourier cosine transforms to figure out the expression for $kA(k)$ yielding the precise behavior you're looking for.